# Как можно обратиться к первому элементу и к первому значению элемента очереди без его удаления?

Tags: python, python-3.x, очередь

Есть код, который перетаскивает нужные элементы из списка в очередь:

```
import queue
some_list = [[1, -2, 3], [2, -3, 4], [3, -6, 7]]
q = queue.PriorityQueue(maxsize=len(some_list ))
for i in range(some_list (neg_list)):
    q.put(neg_list[i][-2::-1])
```

Итого в очереди имеем:

```
[-6, 3]
[-3, 2]
[-2, 1]
```

Как можно обратиться к первому элементу `[-6, 3]` и к первому значению элемента `[-6]`без его удаления из очереди?
В интернете нашел только обращение через q.get(), но он удаляет значение. Или следующее использование оптимально?

```
item = q.get()
# some code with item
q.put(item)
```

Comment: через индексы пробовали? `q.queue[0][1]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ко всем элементам очереди можно всегда обратиться:

```
list(q.queue)
```

соответственно, к отдельному элементу - через индекс:

```
q.queue[0]
q.queue[1][1]
```

Comment: `q.queue` уже `list`, кстати, дополнительно вроде не нужно приводить